# How many automorphisms does the second graph have

Tags: graph-theory

[image: Second graph]

Hello, the second graph should have 2 automorphisms, but I see that none of the vertices has exactly the same adjacent vertices, so that I would be able to switch them and form an automorphism. What automorphisms of the second graph are there?
Thank you!
Also the posted degree of the second graph is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the identity automorphism, and then the reflection automorphism. The reflection swaps $b$ and $d$. Those are the only two automorphisms.

Comment: wow. I wonder why our arrogant prof gives us problem without teaching us about relevant info.

Comment: Also, by swapping b and d, you mean swaps b,c and d,e correct because if b and d can be swapped so can c and e?

Comment: No. I just swap b and d. If I swap c and e after swapping b and d, I get the identity automorphism again.

Comment: okay thank you very much. u should teach discrete math at universities. we lack quality teachers.

Comment: Counting is tough. With graph theory, you have to play around with the subjects. Even with the best professor in the world, you could see a graph theory problem that stumps you even if you covered that subject the entire semester. The trick is to play around with the problem and not give up so easily. Keep working at it and you'll get better!